# If make_shared/make_unique can throw bad_alloc, why is it not a common practice to have a try catch block for it?

Tags: c++, c++11, exception, smart-pointers, nullptr

The CppReference page for make_shared says (same with make_unique)

> May throw std::bad_alloc or any exception thrown by the constructor of T. 
>   If an exception is thrown, the functions have no effect.

This means that std::bad_alloc exeception can be thrown in case of a failure. "the functions have no effect" implicitly means that it cannot return a nullptr. If this is the case, why is it not a common practice to write make_shared/make_unique always into a try catch block?

What is the proper way to use a make_shared? 
Within try catch block? or Checking for nullptr?

Comment: One of the nice things about exceptions (coupled with RAII) is that you don't have to deal with errors when and where they happen, but can do it back up in the call-stack, in a place where it's convenient. Or not at all if the error is fatal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see two main reasons.

1. Failure of dynamic memory allocation is often considered a scenario which doesn't allow for graceful treatment. The program is terminated, and that's it. This implies that we often don't check for every possible `std::bad_alloc`. Or do you wrap `std::vector::push_back` into a try-catch block because the underlying allocator could throw?
2. Not every possible exception must be caught right at the immediate call side. There are recommendations that the relation of `throw` to `catch` shall be much larger than one. This implies that you catch exceptions at a higher level, "collecting" multiple error-paths into one handler. The case that the `T` constructor throws can also be treated this way. After all, exceptions are exceptional. If construction of objects on the heap is so likely to throw that you have to check every such invocation, you should consider using a different error handling scheme (`std::optional`, `std::expected` etc.).

In any case, checking for `nullptr` is definitely *not* the right way of making sure `std::make_unique` succeeds. It never returns `nullptr` - either it succeeds, or it throws.

Comment: That answers my question @lubgr. Thanks. That does mean that expecting bad_alloc exception is not neccessary as it is rare?

Comment: I'd say this depends on the platform you target. On an ordinary 64bit desktop machine, you usually don't have allocation failures as long as you don't deal with massive data in memory. Things might be completely different on some embedded device though.

Comment: Okay! Even in such low memory Embedded devices, it makes sense to have a universal try catch mechanism instead of having try/catch blocks for each make_shared usage. Right?

Comment: You can't generalize that, I think some platforms don't even have a heap. If allocation is an issue on such a device, you should centralize allocation failure handling by using custom allocators anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

Throwing `bad_alloc` has two effects:

- It allows the error to be caught and handled somewhere in the caller hierarchy.
- It produces well-defined behaviour, regardless of whether or not such handling occurs.

The default for that well-defined behaviour is for the process to terminate in an expedited but orderly manner by calling `std::terminate()`.  Note that it is implementation-defined (but, for a given implementation, well-defined nonetheless) whether the stack is unwound before the call to `terminate()`.

This is rather different from an unhandled failed `malloc()`, for example, which (a) results in undefined behaviour when the returned null pointer is dereferenced, and (b) lets execution carry on blithely until (and beyond) that moment, usually accumulating further allocation failures along the way.

The next question, then, is where and how, if at all, calling code should catch and handle the exception.

The answer in most cases is that it shouldn't.

What's the handler going to do?  Really there are two options:

- Terminate the application in a more orderly fashion than the default unhandled exception handling.
- Free up some memory somewhere else and retry the allocation.

Both approaches add complexity to the system (the latter especially), which needs to be justified in the specific circumstances - and, importantly, in the context of other possible failure modes and mitigations.  (e.g. A critical system that already contains non-software failsafes might be better off terminating quickly to let those mechanisms kick in, rather than futzing around in software.)

In both cases, it likely makes more sense for any actual handling to be done higher up in the caller hierarchy than at the point making the failed allocation.

And if neither of these approaches adds any benefit, then the best approach is simply to let the default `std::terminate()` handling kick in.

Comment: **Simply  to let the default handling kick in** - What does this actually mean, @Jeremy?